# AngularJS: Changing variable for an ng-switch using dynamically generated DOM

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, dynamic

This is a little difficult to explain since I can't extract the code that I'm having the most difficulty with. The best I can do is a simple fiddle of what I'm trying to accomplish: https://jsfiddle.net/yLkukw5p/

HTML:

```
<div ng-app = "myApp" ng-controller = "parentController" ng-switch = "properties.selectedMethod">
  <div ng-controller = "childController" ng-switch-when = "id">
    <a ng-click = "survey()">
    Change div
    </a>
  </div>
  <div ng-switch-when = "date">
  div changed
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.factory('vars', function() {
    var properties = {};

    properties.selectedMethod = 'id';

    function setselectedMethod(string){
        properties.selectedMethod = string;
    }

    return {
        properties : properties,
        setselectedMethod : setselectedMethod
    };
});

app.controller('parentController', function($scope, vars) {
    $scope.properties = vars.properties;

    $scope.setSearchMethod = function(method){
        vars.setselectedMethod(method);
    }
});

app.controller('childController', function($scope, $rootScope, $http, vars) {
    $scope.properties = vars.properties;
    $scope.survey = function() {
        vars.setselectedMethod("date");
    }
});
```

Basically, I want to be able to change the variable value in a factory shared between child and parent controllers. The only hiccup I'm running into is that in my case, **the child div is dynamically generated**, and that seems to be the only thing different between the fiddle and my code. I have some JavaScript that adds this DOM:

```
<div onclick = angular.element('#anotherdiv').scope().setSearchMethod('id');> More Info </div>
```

where `anotherdiv` is a div within the childController. When I click this div, I know by debugging that it runs the code in the `vars` factory, but it doesn't update other values? I'm using the "dot" trick so I would think the variables are references and not "shadowing" as some other posts suggested. Any thoughts?

EDIT: Updated the fiddle to be more accurate: https://jsfiddle.net/yLkukw5p/1/
It looks like the `onclick` function using angular.element is the one causing trouble, but I don't know how to work around it.

Comment: is it what you're looking for? https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/yLkukw5p/2/

Comment: @varit05 right, but in my project that div you modified is dynamically generated, and `ngClick` is not a recognized attribute. I'm not sure how to add a div with `ng-click` dynamically.

Comment: Can you give me some idea about how exactly the child div is generated dynamically?

Comment: @varit05 it looks like this: `var data = jQuery("#" + tableId + " td:nth-child(3)");
  var html = "<div onclick = angular.element(document.getElementById('test')).scope().test();> More Info </div>";
  data[1].innerHTML = data[1].innerHTML + html;`   basically, it uses jQuery to insert a div into the second row and third column of a table.

Comment: Are you getting any error if you write like : `var data = jQuery("#" + tableId + " td:nth-child(3)"); var html = "<div ng-click = test();> More Info </div>"; data[1].innerHTML = data[1].innerHTML + html;`

Comment: @varit05 no error, but the resulting div does not execute the `ng-click`

Comment: Please make sure you've test function inside your controller

Comment: @varit05 yes, and i have tested the function with static DOM elements.